# C# order an IEnumerable by custom requirements

Tags: c#, list

So i'm wanting to order an IEnumerable using custom requirements. Basically i wish to order it by DocumentId, but i'm a bit picky / specific so i need them to be ordered like so..

```
1st = ID 3
2nd = ID 5
3rd = ID 2
4th = ID 4
5th = ID 6
```

this is because these ID's match up to an predefind image and the images need to be shown in this order.

anyone think of a way of doing this please.

Comment: please elaborate your question? Its not cleared to be answered.

Comment: Are you trying to sort by odd number DocumentId 1st then even number?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following approach.

```
int[] orderedIds = { 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 }
var result = enumerable.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(orderedIds, x.Id));
```

This assumes that all `orderedIds` contains all possible IDs. If that is not the case, this approach would sort the items with an unknown ID before all others. Most likely this is not what you want, so in this scenario, you might want to use something like this:

```
var result = 
    enumerable.Select(x => new { Item = x,
                                 Index = Array.IndexOf(orderedIds, x.Id) })
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.Index != -1)
              .ThenBy(x => x.Index == -1 ? x.Item.Id : x.Index)
              .Select(x => x.Item);
```

This puts the items with an unknown ID to the end of the result and orders them by ID.

Comment: cheers i think the first one will work as this the only Id's i need to sort by thanks, i'll give it a go

Comment: @rugbylad_28: Please use the updated version with `Array.IndexOf(orderedIds, x.Id)` instead of `orderedIds.IndexOf(x.Id)`

Comment: when i've used both these solutions it returns the error - No overload for Method IndexOf takes 1 arguments

Comment: @rugbylad_28: That's exactly the error that is fixed in the updated version `Array.IndexOf(orderedIds, x.Id)`. Please make sure you use it.

Comment: sorry i didn't see the update, my bad (hadn't refreshed page)